# How to change the number of months of the time plot chart at runtime using a button in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am redrawing the chart to have complete access to changing the properties of the chart.
[image]

Now I am trying to show a specific month on the x axis but not sure how to access any specific month. I have added each month data into separate datasets which are added in the chart.
[image]

For example `var_monthForPop ==1` means only January timeline should be on the x axis of the chart.